# Failing to complete boot (freezing on starting processes)

Tags: boot

When I try and start ubuntu I am suddenly having a strange issue where things boot normally and then they freeze while starting processes (different points each time). I.e. I am frozen at a black terminal screen listing "[  ok ] Started _______" for various processes

If I boot in recovery mode I can access the terminal and things seem to be fine there. Any thoughts? I was recently getting warning messages that I was running out of space in the root filesystem. Could that be the culprit? If so, thoughts on how to solve that problem enough to boot (I did the clean option from the recovery menu and that did not work). Thanks.

Comment: The OS CAN NOT boot if there is no hard disk space left. Yes this is why it crashes on start up.

Comment: How big is the partition you are booting from?

Comment: The boot partition is 20G

Comment: Well you have not said the version of Ubuntu you are using so can not give exact info but I can tell you the min for that is 25 gig if not using an OS that uses snaps and 50 is recommended if using snaps. So either way it was too small to start with.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try and clear enough stuff to boot and then resize the partitions. Thanks!

Comment: Resize  now. Boot from Live Media and run gparted. It is doubtful you can free up enough space to boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)